# Graphics Issue with JFrame in a Game Engine

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, game-engine

I'm creating a "simple" 2D game engine for the block game Collapse for my college class. I am trying to make it such that the JFrame is resized any time a new screen is introduced, and I have made two attempts at it, one that resizes correctly, but doesn't show anything, and one that shows SOMETHING, but doesn't resize.

For this post, I will be showing the code for the second game engine that I have created, as my first attempt was a monolithic version that I ended up having trouble following myself.

First off, for some reason the window will not close with the X button, even though the setDefaultCLoseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) is enacted.

Second (for the second attempt) the JFrame will not resize, but will show a sliver of the test StartMenu

(sorry for links, editor said I have to have rep of 10 before being able to post pictures... smart move, but still annoying)
http://i1148.photobucket.com/albums/o577/FoxnEagle/GraphicsWindow1_zpscqdgsjqh.png

but upon resizing;

http://i1148.photobucket.com/albums/o577/FoxnEagle/GraphicsWindow2_zpsckr4eohs.png

I guess the question of the post is what am I doing wrong to have the window become unresponsive, and be able to make modern art with it?

Collapse.java

```
import gameEngine.*;
import screens.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Collapse{

    private Game game;

    public Collapse(){
        this.game = new Game("Test", null);
        game.getScrMan().setScreen(new StartMenu(game.getScrMan()));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Collapse();
    }
}
```

:||package screens||:

StartMenu.java

```
package screens;

import gameEngine.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StartMenu extends Screen{

    private final ScreenManager scrMan;

    public StartMenu(ScreenManager scrMan){
        super(scrMan);
        this.scrMan = scrMan;
    }

    public void onCreate(){
        JButton b1 = new JButton();
        scrMan.getScrMan().setSize(200, 200);
        scrMan.getScrMan().add(b1);
        System.out.println("got here");
    }

    public void onUpdate(){
    }

    public void onDraw(Graphics2D g2d){
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillOval(10, 10, 10, 10);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(10,10,10,10);
    }

}
```

:||package gameEngine||:

Game.java

```
package gameEngine;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Game{
    private final ImageIcon image;
    private final String title;
    private final GameLoop gameLoop;
    private final ScreenManager scrMan;
    private final InputManager inpMan;
    private final EntityManager entMan;
    private JFrame window;
    private boolean running;

    //constructor and initializer for gameLoop
    public Game(String title, ImageIcon image){
        this.title = title;
        this.image = image;
        window = new JFrame();
        scrMan = new ScreenManager(this);
        inpMan = new InputManager();
        entMan = new EntityManager();
        gameLoop = new GameLoop(this);
        initialize();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(gameLoop);
    }

    private void initialize(){
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  //close on exit
        window.setTitle(title);                                 //set the title
        if(image != null){}                                     //set the image icon NOT IMPLEMENTED YET
        //window.setResizable(false);                               //user cannot resize
        window.setFocusable(true);                              //
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                     //put in center of screen
        window.add(scrMan);                                     //add the 
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
        running = true;
    }


    public JFrame getWindow(){return window;}
    public boolean getRunning(){return running;}
    public ScreenManager getScrMan(){return scrMan;}
    public InputManager getInput(){return inpMan;}
    public EntityManager getEntMan(){return entMan;}

    public void paused(){running = false;}
    public void resume(){running = true;}
}
```

GameLoop.java

```
package gameEngine;

import java.lang.Runnable;

public class GameLoop implements Runnable{
    private final Game game;
    private long time;
    private final int fps = 30;

    public GameLoop(Game game){this.game = game;}

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            while(game.getRunning()){
//System.out.println("running");//debugging
                if(game.getScrMan().getScreen() != null){
                    game.getScrMan().getScreen().onUpdate();
//System.out.println("screen is updating");//debugging
                }
//fps clock, commenting out does not fix problem
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                time = (1000/fps) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
                if(time > 0){try{Thread.sleep(time);}catch(Exception e){}}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ScreenManager.java

```
package gameEngine;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;

public class ScreenManager extends JPanel{
    private final Game game;
    private Screen screen;

    public ScreenManager(Game game){this.game = game;}

    public void setScreen(Screen screen){
        this.screen = screen;
        this.removeAll();
        screen.onCreate();
        game.getWindow().revalidate();
        //game.getWindow().pack();
    }

    public Screen getScreen(){return screen;}
    public Game getGame(){return game;}
    public ScreenManager getScrMan(){return this;}

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(0,0, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Screen.java (StartMenu extends and overrides all functions)

```
package gameEngine;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public abstract class Screen{
    private final ScreenManager scrMan;

    public Screen(ScreenManager scrMan){this.scrMan = scrMan;}

    public abstract void onCreate();
    public abstract void onUpdate();
    public abstract void onDraw(Graphics2D g2d);
}
```

InputManager.java (nothing implemented yet, just a placeholder)

```
package gameEngine;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class InputManager implements KeyListener, MouseListener{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event){
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event){
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event){
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event){
    }
}
```

EntityManager.java and Entity.java are just blank classes

Answer (score 2):

This,

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(gameLoop);
```

runs your game loop in the event dispatch thread, blocking it. So the repaint manager never has a change to draw the contents. You should instead [create](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) the GUI in the event dispatch thread, as modifying or creating swing components from other threads is not safe.

The game loop's timing needs to be done in a way that does not block the EDT. The easiest is using a [swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html); if that proves later to be insufficient, you can switch to another solution, but then you need to pay close attention to thread safety. Swing timer runs the action listener code in the EDT so it's easy to be thread safe that way.

Comment: So I have rebuilt the game engine so that the **GameEngine.java implements Runnable**. In the constructor I have it _invokeLater(this)_ and in the **run()** I have it _invokeLater(this)_ as well. This makes it initialize itself and loop itself. It runs the way I want it to, but I am curious if it actually finishes the job before calling another one. Is there anything wrong with having **run()** invoke itself to make the loop?

Comment: @FoxnEagle As the name of the method says, it gets run "later". The main issue is that it is essentially a busy loop. `invokeLater()` places the runnable in a queue to be run in the event dispatch thread; then calling `invokeLater()` in `run()` places it immediately again to the queue to be run - without any pauses. And sleeping in the EDT would be a *very bad idea*, as during that the program can't do any other UI related tasks either. For a GUI task that is run at constant frequency, you should really use a swing `Timer`.

Comment: Is it then safe to override _paintComponent(Graphics g)_ have a swing Timer installed to limit refreshes, and at the end call _repaint()_? I'm trying to make the loop based of the links given in the answer, but I am also trying to make the game be paused by terminating the _running_ loop, and having it run inside a _while(true)_ loop. But then it either doesn't call paint() at all, or it loses the instantiated Objects when I terminate the _running_ loop

Comment: Oh, just remembered the other invoke, _invokeAndWait()_ and set that in a _while(true)_ loop. It works, but the question in my comment above still stands.

Comment: @FoxnEagle Calling `repaint()` from the timer's action listener would be customary (like doing any other tasks, that should be done periodically). You can `stop()` the timer, when you want to pause, and `start()` it again when you want to resume. It would be possible to have your own loop, but it needs to be in a different thread that the EDT, *and* it must use `invokeLater()` when accessing any swing components. Using a Timer is simpler, so I recommend starting with that. It's very unusual to need `invokeAndWait()` for anything.